# I need to understand why when I add values to my labels I get null?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a form when I check items from `CheckBoxList` which columns I want from an `SQL` `table`, I get a `new Form()` and there I want to add values and add them to SQL. I get null values except for the last. Any suggestions why is that?
[image]

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        query = $"INSERT INTO {DM.comboBox1.SelectedItem} Values(";


        for (int i = 0; i <DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count == i + 1)
            {
                query += "'" + txtBox[i].Text + "')";
                break;
            }
            query += "'" + txtBox[i].Text + "'";
            query += ",";

        }
        myQuery = query;

        Fm1.conn = new SqlConnection($"Server = {Fm1.ServerBox.Text }; Database = { Fm1.DBBox.Text}; Trusted_Connection = True");
        Fm1.cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, Fm1.conn);
        Fm1.conn.Open();
        Fm1.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Fm1.conn.Close();

    }

    private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel() { AutoSize = true };
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {

            txtBox = new TextBox[DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count];
            labels = new Label[DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count];

            labels[i] = new Label();
            for (int j = i; j < DM.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (DM.dataGridView1.Columns[j].Visible)
                {
                    labels[i].Text = DM.dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                    break;
                }
            }
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(labels[i]);

            txtBox[i] = new TextBox();
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(txtBox[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txtBox[i]);
        }

       Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
    }
```

Comment: `txtBox = new TextBox[DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count];` You're instantiating the array on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment as don't have 50. Amy above is correct.

Remove these lines and try again:

```
labels = new Label[DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count];
txtBox = new TextBox[DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count];
```

Update because of comment.

Comment: I think the assignment of both `labels` and `txtBox` should actually be moved just outside the loop, yah? They need to be instanciated with a number of elements equal to `DM.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count`.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson yes, I think so. Amy above said this (not wanting to repeat her)

Comment: Indeed, they should be moved out of the loop.